# Adapting to Samsung S8-like screens with 'blind pixels'

Tags: android, android-layout

How to avoid 'blind pixels'? S8's round-cornered screen may affect layout in a significant way. How to know where I can safely draw anything, and where I have to be aware that some part of drawn pixels may never actually display?

I don't want to force non-fullscreen mode. I just want to know where is my "safe rect". How to get that information?

(possibly in a way that can be applied to every phone no matter what company manufactured it, but device-specific solutions are also very welcome)

**edit: added picture for everybody still in 2016:**
[image: image for 2016 people]

Comment: Care to explain what a blind pixel is?

Comment: Have you tried drawing the layout before asking the question? Did it go wrong?

Comment: @Mauker Have you seen new iPhone X? I think that looking on its screen is the best explanation you need. Same thing is already on Android as Samsung released its S8 and S8+ and LG released G6, also with rounded corners. There are pixels there my friend. GPU wants to draw on these pixels but nobody's there that's why I invented 'blind pixels